# How can I use sbt.IO?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've noticed that many Scala projects use [sbt.IO](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/util/io/src/main/scala/sbt/IO.scala) which has great file system and IO utilities

E.g. useful things like:

```
def gzip(in: File, out: File)
def download(url: URL, to: File)
def copyDirectory(source: File, target: File, overwrite: Boolean = false, preserveLastModified: Boolean = false):
```

However I couldn't find it (funnily enough) in any maven repo officially, what am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scala2.9

```scala
resolvers += Resolver.url("typesafe", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" % "io" % "0.12.4"

scalaVersion := "2.9.3"
```

Scala2.10

```scala
resolvers += Resolver.url("typesafe", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" % "io" % "0.13.9"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
```

Scala2.11

```scala
resolvers += Resolver.url("typesafe", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" %% "io" % "0.13.9"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Comment: Thank you! any idea what is the license for it? can I really use it in a library?

Comment: @EranMedan sbt is under a BSD-style license, see [LICENSE](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/LICENSE)